# CodeIgniter upload file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have written code for uploading a file in CodeIgniter.

Here is the view file code

```
<form method='post' type="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" class="apply_form" id="apply_form">

<input type="file" name="submit_resume" id="submit_resume" class="submit_resume" value="browse"/>
```

Here is the controller file code

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->helper('html');
$this->load->helper('form');

$this->load->library('upload');

$config['upload_path'] = $this->base_url.'/uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'docx|doc|pdf';
$config['max_size'] = '1000';
//$config['max_width']  = '1024';
//$config['max_height']  = '768';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    //$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
}
else
{
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

    //$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
}
```

But nothing is uploading in the uploads folder.
Cant figure out what the issue really is!

Comment: Do you get anything at this $error ?

Comment: actually its going into the if part of the controller code  if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes I would do:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
```

Mention only the relative path and not absolute path.

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('submit_resume'))  //here see the file name
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    print_r( $error );die;
}
```

Just to view the error you are getting.
You must have the correct permission set in your `uploads` folder too.

Comment: i am getting the error Array ( [error] =>
You did not select a file to upload.

)

Comment: You must provide the file name inside the `do_upload` function, the default file name is `userfile`

Comment: do_upload is juz the name of the function ryt??

Comment: yep. the argument it takes is the element's name, in your case it's `"submit_resume"`

Comment: and my function for this CI class should be like this : public function do_upload() ryt?? i am trying it . will revert in few min

Comment: i am getting this error now   The upload path does not appear to be valid.

Comment: where is your `uploads` folder, is it in the root of your project?

Answer (score 0):

The **`permission`** of the folder in which the file is getting uploaded might be the issue.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
```

For changing the permission of above folder, use following command in your terminal -

> `chmod -R 750 /uploads/`

**Explanation:**

chmod 750 changes to permission to read and write for the user.
-R makes is recursive.

Comment: where shall i use chmod??

Comment: In your terminal. chmod -R 777 <path of your folder>

Comment: Which machine are your working on? Linux/Windows/Mac

Comment: terminal saying chmod is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Ok. For windows machine, try this : http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7

Comment: Please stop suggesting to use 777. You're making your file writeable by everyone, which pretty much means you lose all security that the permission system was designed for. If you suggest this, think about the consequences it may have on a poorly configured webserver: it would become incredibly easy to "hack" the website, by overwriting the files.

Instead, use 750 if the user who runs PHP is also the owner of the file.

Comment: @BerryLangerak: Thanks for suggestion. Made changes.